# How to fill a gridview from a list in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview

I have a gridview in my page and i show some search results in it. Here is how i do it:

```
int row = -1;
        int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument as string, out row);

        GridViewRow gdrow = instCourses.Rows[row];

        // *** Get the underlying data item - in this case a DataRow
        DataRow dr = ((DataTable)this.instCourses.DataSource).Rows[gdrow.DataItemIndex];

        // *** Retrieve our context
        string courseCode = dr["CourseCode"].ToString();
        string courseNumber = dr["CourseNumber"].ToString();
        string term = dr["Term"].ToString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = Userfunctions.GetConnectionString();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("SELECT RegisterTable.StudentID, StudentTable.Name, StudentTable.Surname FROM RegisterTable JOIN StudentTable ON RegisterTable.StudentID = StudentTable.ID WHERE RegisterTable.CourseCode = @courseCode AND RegisterTable.Term = @term AND RegisterTable.CourseNumber = @courseNumber",con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseCode", courseCode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseNumber", courseNumber);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", term);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        studList.DataSource = dt;
        studList.DataBind();
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Students who are registered to "+courseCode+ " " + courseNumber +" are listed below:";
```

But i have already done the same query before, and kept the results in a list, let's say the name of the list is searchResults. My question is, instead of querying the database again to fill the table, can i use the items in that list to fill the gridview? Or should i use any other thing instead of gridview to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your list (IEnumerable) as the datasource of your gridview.
No need to query again

```
    studList.DataSource = searchResults;
    studList.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i do this it says The data source for GridView with id 'searchResults' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content. Any idea about the problem?

Comment: look at jadarnel27's comment below. You cannot map fields. You need to convert them to public Properties. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood what you were asking.  You can use a `List<T>` of objects as your datasource in the same way that you are using the DataTable in your example above.  You just have to make sure that you expose the class-variables that you want your GridView to see as public properties - like this:

```
public class Course
{
    public string courseCode { get; set; }
    public string courseName { get; set; }
    public string courseNumber { get; set; }

    //...the rest of your class code...//
}
```

---

If you are going to be reusing that DataTable, I would just store it in the Session.  So where you set it to your datasource:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
studList.DataSource = dt;
```

Also, add it to the Session:

```
Session["mySearchResults"] = dt;
```

Then you can reference that to populate your other list:

```
myOtherList.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["mySearchResults"];
myOtherList.DataBind();
```

Note that if this DataTable is really huge, or if you're going to have a lot of users accessing this application at once, this approach might bring problems (resource-wise on your web server).  But it works as a simple solution.

Comment: Thanks, but actually what i want is to fill the gridview using a list

Comment: @bigO Can you tell us more about the List?  You mean a generic `List<T>`?  What are you putting in the List?

Comment: Yes, i am using a generic list. I put Course objects in my list, course is a class that i created and it has string variables like courseCode, courseName and courseNumber. I want to display these fields in my gridview

Comment: @bigO Ah, that should be no problem then. You just need to make those values public properties in your class (`public String courseName { get; set; }`). Then the GridView will see them. That's why you're getting the error you mentioned in Littlefool's answer.